# Appcelerator Titanium: Open activity without animation

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

In Titanium Alloy I'm trying to open a controller which is a Window without animation.

What I've done is define a new style inside `/platform/android/res/values/activity_no_animation.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.NoAnimation" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

my controller filename is login.js, so in my tiapp.xml I've defined the activity like this (as explained here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/tiapp.xml_and_timodule.xml_Reference-section-29004921_tiapp.xmlandtimodule.xmlReference-activities)

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <application android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionBar">
            <activity url="login.js" android:theme="@style/Theme.NoAnimation" />
        </application>
        <!-- Need to specify at least API level 11 for Titanium SDK 3.2.x and prior -->
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

but when the app starts, after the splash screen I still see the activity animation. What I would expect is for the activity (window) to just show up.

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

For some strange reasons you cannot override **all** animations inside Titanium.

I've asked this question [over here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/177894/android-disable-tabgroup-open--close-animation) with no success.

I've tried patching ti mobile source code and making a custom build. As far as I could get was to disable the opening animation. Closing animation was still playing on some devices.

Answer (score 0):

I found this by working backwards from SDK code, but when calling Ti.UI.Window.open() to actually open the window, supply the animated property set to false:

```
win = Ti.UI.createWindow(/* ... */);
win.open({ animated: false });
```

I'm not familiar with Alloy, but this should be reasonably easy to translate into Alloy.

This works at least in SDK 5.0.2.